# Using Python to create SFTP users in linux

Tags: python, linux, sftp

I created the following to create SFTP users in a linux server. Is there a better way to implement this? The script works by generating a username after checking if the user already exists. Then prompts the user if they want to generate a random password or if they want to create their own. Afterwords, it takes the username and password and creates a new user adding them to a group that has permissions to upload via sftp. I'm mostly concerned with using os.system a lot.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pwd
import string
import random
import os
from getpass import getpass

def generate():
        global username
        username = raw_input("Enter username: ")
        try:
                pwd.getpwnam(username)
                print "Username already exists."
                generate()
        except:
                pass_generator()
                return username

def pass_generator():
        global password
        confirm = raw_input("Randomly generate password? (y/n): ")
        if confirm == "y":
                password = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(6))
        elif confirm == "n":
                p1 = getpass("Enter password: ")
                p2 = getpass("Confirm password: ")
                if p1 == p2:
                        password = p1
                else:
                        print "Passwords do not match. Try again."
                        pass_generator()
        else:
                print "Type y for yes, n for no."
                pass_generator()

def create_account(Username, Password):
        os.system('sudo useradd -d /home/clients/%s -s /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -g sftp-only %s' % (Username, Username))
        os.system('sudo chown root:integration /home/clients/%s' % (Username))
        os.system('sudo chmod 777 /home/clients/%s' % (Username))
        os.system('echo %s:%s | sudo chpasswd' % (Username, Password))

def main():
    generate()
    create_account(username, password)
    print "User %s has been successfully created with password %s" % (username, password)

if __name__ =='__main__':main()
```

Comment: Of course there is a better way: get rid of the globals and replace them with function parameters. There's no way around `os.system` for calling system utilities like `useradd`. Also, the try-except logic in `generate()`, while formally correct, is totally un-idiomatic (and enough failed attempts will result in a stack overflow). Try using the value that `getpwnam` returns, and a loop. The bare `except` clause could get you in trouble in many cases, e.g. when you press `^C`; avoid it.

Comment: @rbart65 You can also use [commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html#commands.getstatusoutput) I think it should work.

Comment: @SidharthShah depending on the python version you should be using subprocess moving forward for all commands. Commands has been deprecated since 2.6.

Comment: Agreed on the `os.system` usage concern - Depending on environment and exposure, could be easy to get compromised. #shellshock. Either consider sanitizing inputs more. On the `chmod 777` line, a username of '`../../*`' or similar would make all your `/` folders world read-write-able. But that's easy to sanitize for usernames. Adding double quotes around things might help but still open to SQL-style injection attacks. Disallowing spaces, dots, hyphens and slashes in the password mitigates a lot.

Comment: @9000 If a user isn't in the system, `getpwnam` will return with a `NameError`, hence why I was using try-except. I can change that to `commands.getstatusoutput`, where it will give me a 0 if the user exists and a 256 if the user doesn't exist. How would a loop help me in this case? Why wouldn't I use an if-else statement?

Comment: @aneroid You bring up such a great point with sanitizing the input. Unfortunately I don't know much in that area, and I'm trying to write this without having to download any APIs - can you point me in the right direction on how to go about that? The only real answer I found on sanitizing inputs used `BeautifulSoup`, which I don't wish to use.

Comment: @rbart65: You can use `except NameError` and be fine. Use a `while True` loop and `break` out of it when user does not exist — though I do appreciate the intuition that loops are logically just recursive functions. Alas, Python does not have tail-call elimination, so deliberately crashing your program via a stack overflow is possible with the recursion instead of a loop.

Comment: @aneroid: I think that forbidding dots and slashes in password is a bit drastic. I'd consider using `popen` and feeding passwords via proper stdin, instead of using `echo`. Regarding #shellshock, I'd rather run the program with shell set to `dash` or `ash` or `busybox` and eliminate the possibility of triggering the bash bug altogether.

Comment: @9000: Agreed, `popen` is the better way to go instead of oversanitizing. But couldn't the eval tick ("`") still cause a problem?

Comment: @rbart65: you could check with `str.search()` or sanitize with `str.replace()`. Call it repeatedly with each character you want to check/remove. Usernames could be limited to letters, numbers, digits, under_score. Also, a single qualifying Regular Expression is less pain. Validate the username against a regex which represents what a valid one could look like. For passing the usernames and passwords to the commands, the comment by @9000 is the way to go: `popen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `subprocess.popen()`. It's safer than `os.system`, and gives you access to the standard buffers as well.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: when I use `subprocess.Popen()` it's only executing the first command before giving up.

Comment: edit: have to put `subprocess.Popen().wait()` to finish the command before going onto the next one